# excel365 - Conditionally format rows based on two string values?

Tags: excel, excel-365

Excel noob here. Lets say I have a sheet.

| . | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 3 | No | No |
| 2 | Betty | 13 | Yes | No |
| 3 | Chris | 12 | No | Yes |
| 4 | Dave | 0 | Yes | Yes |
| 5 | Emma | 1 |  | No |

I want to conditionally highlight cells in multiple ways:

- if column `C` and column `D` both contain the word 'Yes' colour the row green *(e.g. match row 4)*
- if column `C` and column `D` are not the same, colour the row yellow *(e.g. match rows 2,3)*
- if column `C` or `D` are empty, colour the row red *(e.g. match row 5)*

I set up two worksheet conditional formatters

1. `=AND(SEARCH("Yes",$C2)>0,SEARCH("Yes",$D2)>0)` is set to be green
2. `=$C2<>$D2` is set to be yellow
3. `=OR(ISBLANK($C2),ISBLANK($D2))` is set to be red

However, I'm getting mixed results. I get green rows where C and D are No or where C and D are different. I don't get any formatting for the second or third rules.

I tried just matching column values directly; `=$C2="Yes"` doesn't match, hence resorting to SEARCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observed behaviour is because of the commonality between rules 2 & 3, i.e. if C2 differs from D2 then it is, superficially, because the content of those cells differ but, if one of the cells is blank, when the other isn't, then both rules 2 & 3 are satisfied *simultaneously*.

In the screenshot below, I have made the assumption that 'half-blank' rows are to be identified before 'non-equal' rows:
[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested conditional-formatting rules]
the formula for 'equal' rows is

```
=AND(COUNTIF($C1,"*Yes*"),COUNTIF($D1,"*Yes*"))
```

([COUNTIF()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function) is used because it caters for *Yes* being found within a longer string of text and, if not found at all, will return 0, which is interpreted, inside the AND() function, as FALSE, whereas if *Yes* is found then the function will return 1, interpreted as TRUE)

Given the non-independence of your rules 2 & 3 it is important that the rules implemented are prioritised as illustrated in the screenshot, which can be achieved by using the up and down buttons (highlighted) to move the currently-selected rule either up or down.